# copying corrupted images from a dvd

Tags: images, dvd, file-recovery

Are there software you know that can copy images from a DVD? now the problem is there images in the DVD that are corrupt that I won't force to copy, If the software can recover the file and copy it that would be cool, If it cannot then skip the file. The dvd is kinda large and I don't want to sit and wait there. I want the DVD do the decision, If it can recover then recover if it cannot, then skip. And do you know other solution copying corrupt files?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using Alcohol120% with enabled error correction/fast skip/etc. If you are lucky enough, you can create a MDS/MDF/ISO from the DVD and you can recover the images there. IF. Just an idea though.

Comment: Yeah, that was in my mind. I'll try to see if it works. thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: It worked for me in the past. Don't know about the paid version of Daemon tools .. maybe it supports this also? Beats me.